# Why $x^3$ can’t be a solution of $y’’+p(x)y’+q(x)y=0$ with $p$ and $q$ continuous in $]-a,a[$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Any ideas? I found this exercise and I can’t seem to find the trick for the proof. Computed the derivatives, substituted in the equation, substituted $x$ with two symmetrical values in $]-a,a[$, added the equations obtained, but no luck.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think the idea would probably be that $p(x) y' + q(x) y = 3x^2 p(x) + x^3 q(x)$ has a zero of order at least 2 at $x=0$ whereas $y'' = 6x$ has a zero of order 1.  In other words, $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{p(x) y' + q(x) y}{x^2} = 3 p(0)$ but $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{y''}{x^2}$ does not exist giving a contradiction.

Comment: Or simply $y(0)=y'(0)=0$, inserted as initial conditions only the zero solution can result. A contradiction to uniqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting $y=x^3$ in the equation gives
$$ 6x+3x^2p(x)+x^3q(x)=0 $$
which holds for $\forall x\in ]-a,a[$. So
$$ 6+3xp(x)+x^2q(x)=0 $$
holds for $\forall x\in ]-a,a[, x\neq0$ .
Letting $x\to 0$ gives
$$ 6=0 $$
which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding your final step, if you had taken the limit when $x\rightarrow b$, for some $b\in ]-a,a[$, we still needed to get $0=0$, right? Just to make sure I understood…